# How to override config value from @PropertySource used in a @ConfigurationProperties config class in a unit test using @TestPropertySource

Tags: unit-testing, spring-boot

I have a config properties instance with prefix "assets."

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties( prefix = "assets", ignoreUnknownFields = true )
public class AssetsProperties
{
   @NotNull
   private Resource     file;
   
   public Resource getFile()
   {
     return file;
   }

   public void setFile( Resource file )
   {
     this.file = file;
   }
}
```

Its default configuration is defined in:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource( name = "assetsConfig", value = "classpath:com/package/boot/web/ui/assets/config/default-assets-config.properties" )
@Order( LOW_ORDER )
public class AssetsConfig
{
}
```

default-assets-config.properties contains:

```
assets.file=classpath:assets.json
```

In my unit test I want to override the default value using:

```
@TestPropertySource( locations = "classpath:com/package/boot/web/ui/assets/tests/assets-config.properties" )
```

assets-config.properties contains

```
assets.file=classpath:com/package/boot/web/ui/assets/tests/assets.json
```

Unfortunately this value is never injected into AssetsProperties.
What do I do wrong, I don't understand because [spring fmk ref doc says](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#testcontext-ctx-management-property-sources)

> Test property sources have higher precedence than those loaded from the operating system’s environment or Java system properties as well as property sources added by the application declaratively via @PropertySource or programmatically.

Thanks in advance,

Paskos

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've hit a [limitation in Spring Boot](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2198) which means that it ignores properties files configured using `@TestPropertySource`. As an alternative, you can configure one or more inlined properties instead:

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = "assets.file=classpath:com/package/boot/web/ui/assets/tests/assets.json")
```

Comment: Thanks @Andy. I subscribed to the issue and I'll use inline properties while waiting.

Comment: upgraded to spring-boot 1.2.3 and it works now. Thanks